# Invoking the Windows Security Dialog (in C# or VB.NET)

Tags: c#, vb.net, winapi

I would like to know how to invoke the Windows Security Dialog (press ctrl+alt+del on a windows workstation *NOTE: I don't want the task manager!*) programmatically.

ON AN XP WORKSTATION, don't worry about Win7 or Vista

Ideally with a quick example in C# (or VB.NET if you must)

Ive searched many of the DLL's such as `msgina.dll` and I can't find it anywhere!

Alternatively just invoking the change password screen would be nice!

Comment: You can't reasonably make calls to msgina.dll anymore.  GINA was removed in Windows Vista and replaced with a new security model so any answer that you find is going to be dependent on the platforms you are going to support.

Comment: You could crash the user's computer in the hopes he clicks ctrl+alt+del

Answer (score 2):

You can try call [WlxLoggedOnSAS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380570%28VS.85%29.aspx) function from GINA or WlxSasNotify  from WinLogon. 
But, I afraid it won't work. But, maybe it will lead you to working method. And it definitely will not work in Vista/W7.

In other side, it might be that Windows Security Dialog can be called *only* by *secure attention sequence* ( ctrl+alt+del) by securytt reasons.

Answer (score 2):

Security features might be standing in your way to programmatically manage security-related features like Security Dialog through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Del</kbd>. I've been running into the same kinds of problems.

About your request to invoke **password change dialog**.

### IADsUser

"*designed to represent and manage an end-user account on a network [and locally].*"

If you find yourself short on solutions, you might whip up your own quick Windows form with password fields and communicate with the  **Windows [IADsUser Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746340(VS.85).aspx)** using the WinNT provider to bind to a local (instead of network) user account on the XP machine.

```
GetObject("WinNT://MYCOMPUTER/jeffsmith,user") //WinNT provider
```

... and use the **[ChangePassword(..) method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746341(VS.85).aspx)** (links to code sample).

```
usr.ChangePassword szOldPass, szNewPass
```

If you're trying to invoke the Windows features directly to cause the user to trust the process then admittedly a custom form for changing a password might look a bit goofy.

### RunDLL32

Another avenue you might try is programmatically invoking RunDLL32.exe at the command line and targeting the correct Win DLL to bring up the password change dialog box. One forum said the following works in XP if SP2 isn't installed. I can't test it because I'm on Vista.

```
rundll32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL password.cpl
```

You can [Google for many of these](http://www.google.ca/search?rlz=1C1GGLS_enCA342CA342&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=windows+xp++rundll32+shortcut+commands), however it does seem to come up short as far as changing the password or invoking Windows security dialog.

[Microsoft's info about Run32Dll](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/164787)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at the SendInput hook in User32:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310(VS.85).aspx
and
http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SendInput.html

Comment: ctrl+alt+del can't be emulated from software. It causes hardware interrupt which is catched by OS kernel

Comment: i guess you can only send the message not get.

Comment: @drorhan, no. It called *secure attention sequence* and must be produced by user behind physical keyboard for security reasons

Comment: i bet a driver could insert those key strokes to the hardware input stream.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine something like this, get the handle of the desktop, using '[GetDesktopWindow](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/GetDesktopWindow.html)', make sure the focus is set to the handle, and Send a keystroke 'Ctrl+Alt+Del' using '[SendInput](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SendInput.html)' or use the '[SendMessage](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SendMessage.html)' to send the keystrokes to that handle returned by `GetDesktopWindow`. It is not guaranteed to work as that is top-off-my-head.

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround i found on other forum. It works for me.

```
Private Function IsRunAsAdministrator() As Boolean

    Dim wi = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()
    Dim wp = New WindowsPrincipal(wi)

    Return wp.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator)

End Function
```

'i use it on formload, you can have it whenever needed

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    If Not IsRunAsAdministrator() Then
        Dim processInfo = New ProcessStartInfo(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase)
        processInfo.UseShellExecute = True
        processInfo.Verb = "runas"
        Try

            Process.Start(processInfo)

        Catch ew1 As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Sorry, this application must be run as Administrator.")
        End Try
        'Application.Current.Shutdown()
        Application.ExitThread()
    Else
   'your statement here
  End If
End Sub
```